# CSS and HTML5 Modals

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog

I created a modal to open it by clicking on a link, BUT when I click it back to the previous page like when we press the back button of the browser,
here is the html code :

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
<div>
    <a title="Close" class="close">X</a>
    <h2>Modal Box</h2>
    //...content
</div>
```

I added of course css styles.
I have verified, there is nothing wrong, but don't know what is the source of this problem :confused:

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Since there is nothing wrong with the code you posted, you'll need to add a working code snippet that actually reproduce the issue

Comment: You can refer this documentation for getting some idea about modals in bootstrap. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/

Comment: I tried to use it alone in another page, it works properly. I use angularjs in my project thus i use views and it doesn't work, it returns to the last view :/